# Передача логина при авторизации на WordPress в переменную

Tags: wordpress

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при авторизации отправляло логин на редирект в ссылку на страницу. Вот мой код

```
add_filter('login_redirect', '_myplugin_lgn_redirect');
function _myplugin_lgn_redirect() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return '/private-page/' . $current_user->user_login . '.html';
}
```

Но это не срабатывает и вместо логина выдает `/private-page/.html`. Только после того, как я перезагружу страницу авторизации, это срабатывает нормально: `/private-page/user01.html`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В момент срабатывания хука пользователь ещё не залогинен (куки не выставлены), `wp_get_current_user()` не работает. Вот почему ваш код срабатывает только при обновлении страницы.

В хук передаются 4 параметра, вам надо использовать их:

```
function _myplugin_lgn_redirect( $login_redirect, $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        return $login_redirect;
    }

    return '/private-page/' . $user->user_login . '.html';
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', '_myplugin_lgn_redirect', 10, 4 );
```

Если попытка логина была неудачной, то $user будет содержать объект класса WP_Error. В этом случае возвращаем значение редиректа по умолчанию.

А если попытка входа удалась, то используем данные о пользователе, которые переданы в хук четвёртым параметром.

Не забываем в объявлении фильтра указать, что хук примет 4 параметра ( ... 10, 4 ).